# AngularJS Referencing object in array

Tags: angularjs, object, reference

How is AngularJS able to reference an object in an array?

I've tried this:

SETUP:

```
var testarray = [];
var obj1 = {id:1};
var obj2 = {};
var obj3 = {};

testarray.push(obj1);
testarray.push(obj2);
testarray.push(obj3);
```

OPTION 1:

```
var refarr = testarray.filter(function(obj){
                        if(obj.id === 1){
                            return obj;
                        }
                        })[0];
console.log(testarray[0] === refarr); //RETURNS FALSE
```

OPTION 2

```
var refarr = testarray[0];
console.log(testarray[0] === refarr); //RETURNS FALSE
```

OPTION 3:

```
var refarr = {};
angular.copy(testarray[0], refarr);
console.log(testarray[0] === refarr); //RETURNS FALSE
```

How to solve this?

Comment: Your filter function is wrong, it should return a boolean. Like in `return obj.id && obj.id === 1`;

Comment: OPTION 1 and 2 returns `true`. OPTION 3 returns `false` and these results are quite expected. Not clear what you are trying to solve.

Comment: That doesn't have much to do with angular. It's just JavaScript. What do you mean by "RETURNS FALSE"? Do you test the returned value (which is undefined) or the printed value? Your first 2 tests are printing true here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your filter function is incorrect, it should be a predicate function, namely, it should return a boolean:

```
var refarr = testarray.filter(function(obj){
    return obj.id && obj.id === 1;
})[0];

console.log(testarray[0] === refarr); //YIELDS TRUE


var refarr = testarray[0];
console.log(testarray[0] === refarr); //YIELDS TRUE
```

Comment: Actually everything is either falsy or truthy in JavaScript. If obj.id is 1, it returns obj, which is truthy. Otherwise, it returns undefined, which is falsy. But I agree that this was probably not the intention of the OP.

Comment: For filter, returned value anyway coerced to boolean. But it still for good coding practice should return boolean.